How to reply to reviewers who ask for more work by responding that the paper is complete as it stands?
I have a paper under review at a journal. Reviewers have very positive feedback, but have brought up a few of the limitations of the method (which I had described and suggested as future work) and requested these be addressed in a revision. What is a good way to politely yet firmly respond to such requests? I do not think such additional work is necessary for publication, as the paper already has a lot of contributions, in my opinion. And, even from a readability and focus perspective, this paper is already substantially longer and has more "going on" than the typical paper in this journal, which made it difficult to write. Of course, these are my subjective opinions, and it's hard to offer objective reasons for whether or not "future work" belongs in "present work".
Edit: Related questions and answers focus on how to negotiate the amount of work in revisions with the editor, especially for authors with limited resources to do such additional work. In this question,  I'm focusing on whether (and if so, how) to argue that doing more work will not make the paper better, because it already covers a lot of ground.

Positive this has been asked here multiple times. First similar but not identical question I found: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/53909/63475 Someone else may find some that are closer.

This question is similar to: How to respond a reviewer's reply when he is asking about much more to be discussed?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Anyon I've edited the question to explain its difference in focus from related questions.

To be clear, you're sufficiently firm on this that you'd rather have the paper rejected than add any of the requested material?

@NateEldredge -- basically. For example, one of the requested additions requires a substantially different set of skills, so while I could do it in principle, someone from that different subfield could do a better job -- and it's substantial enough to get published on its own, in my opinion.

I'd completely agree with @avid's answer. Introductions that only explore the broad area in which the research was done, without defining a narrow purpose to the research, invite the reviewer to request work on the area of the broad field that is more interesting to them. Normally the problem is that the reviewer can't see that the paper has met its aims because the aims aren't clearly specified or are too broad. Clearly laying out the research question the paper seeks to answer at the outset, will help to show that it has delivered on that aim and that additional work would be beyond the scope of the current paper.
If a research question is clearly specified at the outset, it is easy to politely respond with "Great idea, but beyond the scope of this paper in answering the research question - {repeat question stated in introduction}"
For your immediate challenge, an appropriate response would be to edit the introduction and make the purpose and research question of the paper clear, and then state that you have made that change and that while you agree with their brilliant idea, it is beyond the scope of this paper as you have now clarified.

When dealing with reviews, it's always a good idea to stop and think about why the reviewer has made a particular request. As medics might say, "focus on treating the disease, not the symptoms". Sometimes, reviewers' comments and questions reveal that your manuscript is not currently conveying the same picture of your work as you have in your head. Often, the solution lies in rewriting other parts of your paper in order to set the reader on a path where those questions never arise.
For example, a reviewer who asks for detailed comparisons with other methods may be approaching your work as a practical tool that is ready for immediate use, whereas you intend it to be more of a conceptual contribution with implementation details still to be worked out. This mismatch in expectations probably means that you need to look again at your introduction and discussion sections, and be more explicit in defining what the work is - and isn't - meant to achieve.
So, to answer your question directly: rather than responding to the editor with a point-blank refusal, think about whether there is an underlying point that should be addressed: it's much better to be able to point to some meaningful change you've made to the manuscript.

Disagree - no revision: We thank the reviewer for the suggestion to incorporate surveying of Guadeloupe raccoon habitats to augment our present study.  While we agree that this would be a useful object of study, and would make an interesting extension to our existing work, it is beyond the scope of our present study and we prefer to leave this as future work.  We are satisfied that our coverage of Eastern raccoons is a valuable object of study in its own right and so we do not propose to make the suggested extension in the present paper.  The suggested extension is something that we will consider as future research.

This, along with a sentence or two in the discussion to mollify the reviewer, acknowleging work yet to be done that might be important or interesting, is often enough.

You've made me want to know more about Guadeloupe raccoon habitats.

@camden_kid: Objective achieved.  ;)

At the end of the day, the reviewers think that the paper would be better with the additions, and you think that it wouldn't. If you really don't want to do the additional work, then the editor will have to resolve the impasse you find yourself in, and I think that the questions linked to in the comments are the right starting point for how to negotiate this with the editor.

The author hasn't gone so far as to say the paper wouldn't be better if the work were done -- merely that the paper is a complete work in and of itself.
